# Spring Boot Application cannot connect to server through VPN

Tags: java, spring-boot, centos7, vpn, openconnect

I have a spring boot application that connects to a server through vpn. It works well on windows but when deployed on linux server it throws

```
org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceIOException: I/O error: Read timed out; nested exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:561) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

The linux OS is Centos. The vpn client used on windows is AnyConnect while Linux client is OpenConnect. Any ideas on how I can solve this?

Comment: Configure the OS firewall to allow the connection.

Comment: @Andreas I shut down the firewalld service and it wont still connect

Comment: Maybe SELinux is interfering.

Comment: @Andreas SELinux is disabled on the system